# horizontal align h2 and a elements

Tags: css

I have an `h2` and an `a` element in a div like this:

```
<div>
    <h2>Header...</h2>
    <a href="#">the link</a>
</div>
```

I wanna align the anchor element right next to the h2 element horizontally **without using display inline-block**. Also, if I use `float:left` on the h2 element and `float:right` on the a element, they are gonna be too far apart (I want them to be right next to each other)

Any help please

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to use inline-block?

Comment: cause IE 7 does not support it

Comment: I guess that is as good of a reason as any. Though, I would not develop for IE7 primarily. I would create alternates for IE7. As long as you are good in IE8+ you should be fine. IE7 user base is pretty low these days. Also inline-block IS supported in IE7 on elements that are by default inline, just in case you didn't know.

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant IE 7 does not support inline:block on non-inline elements and there are still a good amount of IE 7 users theses days. So you can't totally ignore IE 7

Comment: I don't know about your users, but ours is 580 of 40,000 monthly visits. A tad more than 1%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h2 {
float: left;
}

a {
float: left;
}
```

Adjust the `margin` between them to your needs and don't forget to use the clear property *after* those [two elements](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

Put the anchor inside the header? Use a float? Have you tried anything?

Float them both left and put a right margin on the H2. Add as much margin as you need.